# How to bind directly to a control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls

I've created a user control that works together with a RichTextBox. The user control needs to work with the RichTextBox, so I've created a dependency property like this:

```
    public static DependencyProperty RichTextEditControlProperty;

    static RichTextBoxToolbar()
    {
        RichTextEditControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RichTextEditControl", typeof(RichTextBox), typeof(RichTextBoxToolbar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    public RichTextBoxToolbar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public RichTextBox RichTextBoxControl
    {
        get { return (RichTextBox)GetValue(RichTextEditControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RichTextEditControlProperty, value); }
    }
```

However, I do not know how I can set this property in XAML. I've tried like this

```
my:RichTextBoxToolbar Margin="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                      RichTextBoxControl="{Binding , ElementName=headerText}"
```

where headerText is the name of the RichTextBox.

But get the following error:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'RichTextBoxControl' property of type
>   'RichTextBoxToolbar'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a
>   DependencyObject. C:\Users\stefan.CORP\Documents\Visual Studio

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property name in static DependencyProperty identifier is incorrect.

```
DependencyProperty.Register("RichTextEditControl", typeof(RichTextBox), 
              typeof(RichTextBoxToolbar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

It should be `RichTextBoxControl` instead of `RichTextEditControl`.

**OR**

Rename wrapper CLR property to name `RichTextEditControl`:

```
public RichTextBox RichTextEditControl
{
    get { return (RichTextBox)GetValue(RichTextEditControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RichTextEditControlProperty, value); }
}
```

**Registered property name and wrapper property name should be in sync always.**

Comment: was gonna do that, but had to wait 4 minutes, now 1 minute :)